# congruences of level 1 and level p modular forms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, modular-forms, congruences

I've been carrying out some experiments on the computer and I noticed the following congruence phenomenon: fixing a prime $p$, it seems that any modular form over $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and of weight $k \geq p+1$ is congruent $\pmod{p}$ to some modular form over $\Gamma_0(p)$ and of weight $k-(p-1)$.

(Edit: by congruent I mean the formal q-expansions at infinity are congruent).

Of course the case where $k = p+1$ is a result of Serre in his "p-adic zeta functions" paper.

I can prove the statement above is true when $p \equiv 11 \pmod{12}$ and $k \geq p+5$. I'm interested to know if someone knows if this is true in general and possibily a proof or a reference. Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at Jochnowitz's two papers in Trans AMS 270 (1982)? There might be something relevant there.

Comment: Scott Ahlgren and I considered some extensions of Serre's results in higher weights in our paper "Higher Weierstrass points on $X_0(p)$" in Transactions of the AMS 355 (2003), 1521-1535.  See section 4 there.  We work out things more in the opposite direction though from your question, relating forms on $\Gamma_0(p)$ to ones on $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ rather than the other way around, but maybe it will be helpful.

Comment: Isn't this Hida's "control theorem"?